# Не работает вывод всех данных из БД

Tags: python, sqlite

Возникла проблема. Есть бот для **VK**. Также работаю с БД - **SQLite**. Есть база, с данными от транспорте: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запросе определённой командой боту, бот должен вывести весь список транспорта:

```
       Connect = sqlite3.connect('TheTruckerDB.db')
       Cursor = Connect.cursor()

       SQLCar = """SELECT name,kyzov,color,engine,ves,boxcar,kabina,rule,status,price FROM firstCar"""
       Cursor.execute(SQLCar)

       for num, (Name, Kyzov, Color, Engine, Ves, Boxcar, Kabina, Rule, Status, Price) in enumerate(Cursor.fetchall(), 1):
              mess = f"[{num}]\t=================\n\nНазвание:\t{Name}\nКузов:\t{Kyzov}\nЦвет:\t{Color}\nДвигатель:\t{Engine}\nГрузо подъёмность:\t{Ves}\nКоробка передачи:\t{Boxcar}\nКабина:\t{Kabina}\nРасположение руля:\t{Rule}\nСтатус транспорта:\t{Status}\nЦена:\t{Price}\n\n"

       send_message(vk, peer_id, message=' /  Покупка транспорта:\n\n Баланс: ' + str(MoneyPlayer[0][0]) + '$\n\n' + mess)
```

Трабл в том, что бот, выводит **НЕ ВЕСЬ СПИСОК**, а только **ПОСЛЕДНИЙ ЭЛЕМЕНТ ИЗ БАЗЫ**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы в цикле ничего не делаете кроме перезаписывания переменной mess. После выхода из цикла в ней остается последнее значение.

Comment: @vitidev, Почему же тогда, точно такая же схема работала в моём и другом проекте. Что мне делать нужно, чтобы исправить?

Comment: Похоже вы пытаетесь собрать строку. Самое простое решение mess+=

Comment: @vitidev, Вот как раз я так и пробовал, но выходит вот такая ошибка:`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mess' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Вы же её не инициализировали, задайте до цикла `mess = ''`

Comment: @vitidev, Работает, спасибо, возьму на заметку!!